# C: fread() always returns 0 when reading a .raw file

Tags: c, pointers

I know this question has already been asked a couple of times, however none of the answers given worked for me. I have a struct with 2 int variables and an unsigned char pointer, and I'm creating a pointer to this struct. Then I want to modify the values of the 2 int variables, and use fread() to take a .raw file (located in the resource files folder, maybe it needs to be elsewhere?) and put it into the unsigned char pointer. However fread() always returns 0, and the program crashes when I try to use free() on the struct pointer. Here's my code so far:

Struct:

```
typedef unsigned char UCHAR;
struct IMAGERAW
{
    int height;
    int width;
    UCHAR* image;
};
typedef struct IMAGERAW IMAGE;
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    IMAGE *img;
    img = read_image();


    free(img->image);
    free(img);
}
```

read_image():

```
IMAGE *read_image()
{
    IMAGE* img;
    FILE* fpI;
    int height = 1409;
    int width = 1690;
    int freadReturn;

    fpI = fopen("file.raw", "rb");


    img = (IMAGE*)malloc(sizeof(IMAGE));
    img->height = height;
    img->width= width;
    freadReturn = fread(img->image, sizeof(UCHAR), img->height * img->width, fpI);
    printf("fread() returns : %d", freadReturn);
    fclose(fpI);

    return img;
}
```

The freadReturn variable is always set to 0 (I believe it should be set to height * width), and the program gives an error at the line "free(img->image);". The dimensions are correct, if I change them the program crashes earlier, and so is the file name, so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `img->image` is just a pointer. I cannot see that you allocate space for the bytes it is supposed to point to.

Comment: @BoP Yeah, I just realised that... Not sure how I missed it.

Comment: read_image() is also returning a local pointer.  This variable is now out of scope so you shouldn't use the value in main()

Comment: `fpI = fopen("file.raw", "rb");` The file is opened without a path, so the system will try to find it in "the current directory", whatever that is. Some IDEs are known to move this all over the place. No guarantees that it is the directory of the executable, so a good idea to test the returned value before using it.

Comment: @jmq  read_image() returns the VALUE of a local variable that happens to be a pointer obtained via malloc().  This is not bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BoP mentionned, I somehow forgot to assign memory for the unsigned char pointer of the struct. So I added

```
img->image = (UCHAR*)malloc(img->height * img->width);
```

just above the line with fread(), and now fread() returns a correct value.